# Integer solutions to $y^2+2=x^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

What  theories  do I  use to  find  the  integer  solutions  of  $$y^2+2=x^3\ ?$$

Extremely sorry  for  no  work  on  my  part. I  could  not  begin  actually.

Comment: See page $7$ of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf

Comment: This might help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473180/the-diophantine-equation-x2-2-y3

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279001/solving-the-mordell-equation-y2-x3-%E2%88%92-2-what-would-be-a-general-strategy

Comment: Or see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652143/finding-integer-cubes-that-are-2-greater-than-a-square-x3-y2-2?lq=1) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169765/by-considering-zsqrt-2-show-that-x22-y3-only-has-two-integer-solutions?lq=1) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704791/number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation?lq=1) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593631/integer-solutions-to-y22-x3?lq=1).